# Which is better - using String or File as parameter type for methods that take filenames

Tags: java, file-io

I have a couple of methods which take filenames as parameters. My doubt is that what is better  way to declare the parameters of these methods.

- Should the parameter be of type `String`

  ```
  void normalizeData(String inFile)
  ```
- Or should I explicitly declare the parameter as `File`.

  ```
  void normalizeData(File inFile)
  ```

Personally I find `File` more intuitive but want to know about what is the best practice for such things.

Comment: This would be a matter of personal taste. IMO it would be better using `File` as parameter, but in the `String` implementation you can do `File file = new File(inFile); normalizeData(file);` and have no problems :).

Comment: Preference is to use `File` as it leaves no doubt as to the intended input.  `String` can become ambiguous.  What if you want to allow a developer to pass a `String` value to be normalised at some stage in the future (that they have already loaded them selves)?

Comment: Have them both.

Comment: It depends on your API. Will the user have to provide file objects or do you want him to be able to input a string?

Comment: Completely Agreed with @LuiggiMendoza.. infact this is the answer to this question :)..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Utility method - Pass a File or String?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2796137/utility-method-pass-a-file-or-string)

Comment: Also, if this is Java 7: use `Path`, not `File`

Comment: I've voted to close as "not constructive". There is not a single correct answer for this and much debate will ensue.

Comment: @TheNewIdiot I can't find this as duplicate. Did you understand the question to begin with?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I can find this as an exact duplicate , just the original has some code in the method to ponder upon .

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Please explain me how it differs from the other question .

Comment: @TheNewIdiot nope, you're right. I'll just go to have a nap.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I would pass an [`java.io.InputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html) - this makes the code easier to test and doesn't bind it to the file system.

This way your code ends up like:

```
public void normalizeData(InputStream in)
{
  ...
}
```

And calling it:

```
myObject.normalizeData(new FileInputStream(myFile));
```

Or

```
myObject.normalizeData(new FileInputStream("c:/myfile.txt"));
```

Or in a test

```
myObject.normalizeData(new ByteArrayInputStream("some test data".getBytes()));
```

Comment: +1 it also allows to reference a file which is in a jar/zip.

Comment: +1 Stop making the answer better, I can only up vote it once :P

Comment: @MadProgrammer I can still upvote... wait, now I can't.

Comment: From me and from all the voters that want to vote again, +1.

Comment: love your answer @NickHolt

Answer (score 4):

Think about using multiple overloaded methods to give the user of the API the choose.

Also think about passing an `InputStream` as it is possible that the user of the API wants to use any in memory representation of the data.

Answer (score 1):

The design depends on many parameters, such as, who is going to use this method. Is it going to be overloaded, is it internal, package level or public API. I would tend to be general and offer two overloaded methods:

- one which passes in the `Path` which is a common way of specifying the path to a file
- and one which passes in the `InputStream`, i.e. general representation of input stream of bytes

  public void normalizeData(Path filePath) //Path is a common way for specifying file path

  public void normalizeData(InputStream) //general representation of input stream of bytes

But as I said, it depends on your project specification.

Answer (score 0):

If you pass the string, you have control in the method over how the file is opened, and the file handle managed. You are centralising that code. If you pass the `File` object, then you are duplicating the file handling code everywhere this is called. So I'd have a strong preference for the former.

Comment: *If you pass the string, you have control in the method over how the file is opened* can you explain how?

Comment: How can you determine if the `String` is a file and not data the user whats to processed?

Answer (score 0):

It depends whether you want the file hanlde outside the normalizeData method or inside it only. If you want to do something on file prior or after calling your normalizeData method then create a file object outside normalizeData method and pass the reference to the method. If ONLY your normalizeData method need to work on the file object then simply pass the filename to it.

Depends on your need and how you want to handle your file.