# Return a file from java method

Tags: java, apache-poi, fileoutputstream, filewriter, filehandle

I have created a method which accepts the JSON response and export the data to Excel and CSV file. I want the method to accept the filename as a parameter, and return the File/FileHandle object from the method.

Can anyone help me regarding this?

I am using below code to export data from **creteExcel** and **createCSV**.

```
public void createExcel( PageModel pageModelRequest,PageModel pageModelResponse ){
        FileOutputStream outputStream=new FileOutputStream(new File("GridData.xlsx"));
        createGrid(pageModelResponse, sheet, workbook);
        workbook.write(outputStream);
        System.out.println("Excel Written");    
        outputStream.close();
        workbook.close();
}

public void createCSV(PageModel pageModelRequest,PageModel pageModelResponse){
        String csvFile = "/Users/abhinak4/Desktop/GridData.csv";        
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(csvFile);
        createGrid(pageModelRequest, pageModelResponse, writer);
}
```

In the method `createGrid`, I am creating the workbook for excel, and I am appending the data, to the `writer` (writer.append).

I want to know, how can I accept the fileName as parameters for `createExcel` and `createCSV` method, and return the file with the same name containing the data?

Comment: Can't you change the signature of the methods - return type and parameters?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which is better - using String or File as parameter type for methods that take filenames](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17142469/which-is-better-using-string-or-file-as-parameter-type-for-methods-that-take-f)

Comment: **For Excel**:I can send the fileName as String parameter, but I am using FileOutputStream to write the data. So can I return FileOutputStream directly fro mthis method, or do I need to convert it into File object. If I need to convert , then how ?
**For CSV**: I am writing data through fileWriter. Can I directly return the fileWriter, or do I need to convert it into file object. If so, then how do we convert it ?

Answer (score 1):

Use this way and you are able to get a file object

```
   File file = new File(fileName);
   FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
   workBook.write(outputStream);
```

My details explanation answer was deleted by someone so I explained here

Answer (score 0):

**I want the method to accept the filename as parameter :** You can send a `String`, A `File` Object or `InputStream` - `createExcel(PageModel req, PageModel resp, File yourFileObj)` 
 **And return the `File` object from the method :** The signature becomes: `public File createExcel()`

Comment: **For Excel**:I want to send the fileName as String parameter, but I am using FileOutputStream to write the data. So can I return FileOutputStream directly fro mthis method, or do I need to convert it into File object. If I need to convert , then how ?
**For CSV**: I am writing data through fileWriter. Can I directly return the fileWriter, or do I need to convert it into file object. If so, then how do we convert it ?