# Difficulty in naming functions

Tags: function, naming

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Anyone else find naming classes and methods one of the most difficult part in programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/421965/anyone-else-find-naming-classes-and-methods-one-of-the-most-difficult-part-in-pro)

Sometimes it seems i cant really find any name for a function i am writing, can this be because the function is not cohesive enough?

What do you do when no good name for a function comes to mind?

Comment: There are two hard problems in computer science: (1) Cache invalidation; (2) Naming things; (3) Off-by-one errors.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/421965/anyone-else-find-naming-classes-and-methods-one-of-the-most-difficult-part-in-pro

Comment: @Greg Hewgill: I bet if Phil Karlton were still alive, he'd love that.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For naming functions, just avoid having simply nouns and rather name them after verbs. Some pointers:

1. Have function names that are unique visibly, e.g. don't have `validateInput()` and `validateUserInput()` since it's hard to say what one does over another. Also, avoid having characters that look very similar, e.g. the number 1 and lowercase 'l'. Sometimes it makes a difference.
2. Are you working on a project with multiple people? You should spend some time going over naming conventions as well, such as if the function name should have underscores, should be camelCase, etc.
3. Hungarian notation is a bad idea; avoid doing it.
4. Think about what the function is doing. The cohesion that you mentioned in your question comes to mind. Generally, functions should do just one thing, so don't name it `constructCarAndRunCar()` but rather have one function that constructs and another that runs it. If your functions are between, say 20 and 40 lines, you're good.
5. Sometimes, and this depends on the project, you might also want to prefix your function names with the class if the class is purely procedural (only composed of functions). So if you have a class that takes care of running a simulation, name your functions `sim_pauseSimulation()` and `sim_restartSimulation()`. If your class is OOP-based, this isn't an issue as much.
6. Don't use the underlying data structures in the functions themselves; these should be abstracted away. Rather than having functions like `addToVector()` or `addToArray()`, have them be `addToList()` instead. This is especially true if these are prototypes or the data structures might change later.
7. Finally, be consistent in your naming conventions. Once you come up with a convention after some thinking, stick to it. PHP comes to mind when thinking of inconsistent function names.

Happy coding! :)

Comment: Wow, nice list, The Hungarian notation is some of the worst things MS propagated, even MS have problems to get rid of the released demon...

Comment: Tell me about it :)
I worked at MS last summer and Hungarian notation was terrible. Imagine having a long pointer to a WCHAR string: `LPWSTR *`.

Comment: I don't personally use Hungarian notation and never have - but what about it makes it so terrible?

Comment: Adding the type was unnecessary for me because as a programmer and developer, I felt that I should know the function and data types that I'm dealing with.

As I said before, this is especially bad if you're refactoring code. Instead of having a linked list called clientList, you'd have LLClientList with HN. If you decide an array is better, you also need to change all of the other instances of the variable and you're forced to think of type when using variables with HN, not use as it should be.

Comment: @Jamie It shows a predominant focus on types. Programming has evolved nowadays to where usage and interfaces are more important than the actual types we use. Also as SHC pointed out, if a type ever changes, it requires changing the name of every single instance where the type is used in the client code even if the interface and usage remains exactly the same. Finally it burdens the users with implementation details that they may not even have to know. A lot of windows API classes and structures, for instance, might as well be opaque to the user: they just pass them around in API functions.

Comment: [...] The information is irrelevant, so to speak. Finally, if one writes code in a way where one needs to know the exact type of an object and it's not obvious, then the code probably needs to be organized better. Hungarian notation is not an excuse to wrote 2000 line functions or a class/struct with 500 members.

Comment: @jdehaan: Hungarian notation: some people love it, some hate it. Personally I love it and it helps me to spot errors (e.g. naming the container vec, map, lst or deq helps me to see if its iterator variants are not broken). I am not a big fan of this 'auto' convention some C++ guru's are dictating. However Hungarian notation is more for variables than for function naming.

Comment: @stinky472 good explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Give it your best-shot and re-factor later if it still doesn't fit.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes it could be that your function is too large and therefore doing too many things.  Try splitting up your function into other functions and it might be clearer what to call each individual function.

Don't worry about naming things with one or two words.  Sometimes if functions do something that can be explained in a mini-sentence of sorts, go ahead and name the function a little longer if it'll help other developers understand what is going on.

Another suggestion is to get feedback from others.  Often others who come from another perspective and seeing the function for the first time will have a better idea on what to call the function.

Answer (score 2):

I follow following rule: Name according to the **purpose** (Why? - design decision) and not to the contents (What, How? - can be seen in the code).

For functions it is almost always an action (verb) followed by the noun of parameters and (or results. *(Off-topic but for variables do not use "arrayOfNames" or "listOfNames", these are type information but simply "names")*. This will also avoid inconsistencies if you refactor the code partly.

For given patterns like object creation, be **consistent** and always use the same naming like "Create..." (and not sometimes "Allocate..." or "Build..." otherwise you or your collegues will end up in scratching their head wound)

Answer (score 0):

Go to [www.thesaurus.com](http://www.thesaurus.com) and try to find a better suited name though synonyms.

Comment: It also comes with experience. There is many magic words in programming like: handler, repeater, builder, utils, convertor, manager and so on. When you read a lot of code and books about programming you bit by bit find out these words and situations when they can be used

Comment: Usually when something is best-named "Manager" you've got a problem.

Comment: I disagree. In .Net you have lot of managers. I wouldn't say they are badly named or .Net have problems in these particular parts. Manager is just a name as any other. Check out: CommandManager, ApplicationManager, ResourceManager, PropertyManager, SecurityManager... I could name at least 100 managers in .Net framework.

Comment: Do *not* use a thesaurus to come up with 213 ways of phrasing the same concept in names. Here (in stark difference to prose) repeating the same words is *good* as far as it helps the reader to figure out what is going on or see similarities.

Answer (score 0):

Almost as important as the function name is that you are consistent with comments.  Many IDEs will user your properly formatted comments not only to provide context sensitive help for a function you might be using, but they can be used to generate documentation.  This is **invaluable** when returning to a project after a long period or when working with other developers.

In academic settings, they provide an appreciated demonstration of your intentions.

A good rule of thumb is [verb]returnDescription.  This is easy with GetName() type functions and can't be applied universally.  It's tough to find a balance between unobtrusive and descriptive code.

Here's a [.Net convention guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229045.aspx), but it is applicable to most languages.

Comment: I wholeheartedly disagree. I frequently find that the best commented code is the hardest to read, and usually also the most error-prone. At uni teachers would tell us that commenting code was the cat's pj's, but years of experience has taught me otherwise. Good code truly is code that requires no inline comments, because the functions are in par with the systemes architechture. "Make sense - not comments" is what I always say.

Comment: @Banang  I appreciate the perspective.  Comment clutter is a problem and shouldnt be used in place of'good design.  Like you said http://stackoverflow.com/questions/184618/what-is-the-best-comment-in-source-code-you-have-ever-encountered/694644#694644

Comment: @MiaClarke, as the saying goes, "if the code and the comments disagree, both are wrong." Just repeating the algorithm in the comments is confusing/redundant. Just an overview of the function, design decisions, comment where something tricky is being done, note possible problem points. Perhaps add a sort of changelog for bugs (or perhaps entrust that one to your version control sofware, *with enough details*).

Answer (score 0):

I find it easier to name functions when I don't have to cut back on the words. As long as your not doing javascript for the google start page you can do longer names.

For example you have the method `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`and`mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification` in apples cocoa framework.

As long as it's clear what the function is doing you can name it whatever you want and refactor it later.

Comment: ifTheNameIsSoLongItIsEasyToConfuseItWithAnotherSimilarOne it is just a *bad* name. "Refactor later" won't ever happen, as you get familiar with the (bad) name, or it gets used all over the place and is too much work to change.

Answer (score 0):

As a practical rule of my own, if a function name is too long, it should be atomized in a new object. Yet, i agree with all posts above. btw, nice noob question