# Need inspiration for naming classes and methods

Tags: oop, coding-style, naming-conventions

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Anyone else find naming classes and methods one of the most difficult part in programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/421965/anyone-else-find-naming-classes-and-methods-one-of-the-most-difficult-part-in-pro)
>   [What’s the best approach to naming classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38019/whats-the-best-approach-to-naming-classes)

Finding appropriate abstraction names can sometime be time-consuming, especially if your mother tongue is not english.  I was wondering if there exists somewhere some sort of online glossary/dictionary describing program-related concepts.  We all know about Design Patterns from GoF but I'm looking for a much more complete lexicon, including relationships between concepts.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Anyone else find naming classes and methods one of the most difficult part in programming?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/421965/anyone-else-find-naming-classes-and-methods-one-of-the-most-difficult-part-in-pro) or [What's the best approach to naming classes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38019/whats-the-best-approach-to-naming-classes)

Comment: I was not asking for naming guidelines but rather for a list of concepts that I can use during my naming task. Or said another way, I'm looking for a programming-oriented on-line thesaurus, something that will tells me the subtle differences between (example):
*item and element 
*reply and response 
*query and request
*handle, process, execute and perform
*attribute and property
*clear and reset
*start vs. begin
*stop vs. end vs. terminate
*continue vs. resume
*settings, configuration, data, info

Being able to browse and navigate between definitions would be interesting.

Answer (score 1):

You know that there *are* conventions for naming artifacts in a program?

For example, Java has come up with a pretty strong and reliable way of naming classes, methods and attributes.

Wikipedia has this to say about naming convention (not too helpful, but still interesting) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)

Here is a page from Central Washington University (with Java, but still helpful for other programming languages) : http://www.cwu.edu/~gellenbe/javastyle/naming.html

Other article here : http://drupal.star.bnl.gov/STAR/comp/sofi/soft-n-libs/standards/NamingAdvice

But basically, naming a method usually start with a action, then a noun, etc.

For example:

```
$obj.addObservers(...);  // action, noun
$obj.setPrice();         // action, noun
$obj.getModelFromDb();   // action, noun, preposition, noun
$obj.setActive(...);     // action, noun
$obj.isActive();         // yes (true) or no (false) statement
$obj.canEdit();          // yes (true) or no (false) statement
$obj.setCanEdit();       // action, attribute
// etc.
```

Avoid using negative method naming, ex: `$obj.cannotConnect();` which will simply confuse everyone. (This is also true when prompting, ex: "You are about to delete this file, do you want to abort?" ... choosing 'no' thinking you are going to delete a file and it was a mistake will do the opposite...)

Back to method naming;

- your method names should be as short as possible, but avoid using acronyms, unless the method name is too long (this is a judgement call here);
- methods should be self explanatory and self documented;
- avoid using prefixes, unless you are working with non-OOP languages (pretty rare these days). Your prefix should be your class, or namespace, etc.
- each method should have only one function (one purpose) if you method does more than one thing, consider splitting that method into many, and call each of them inside a method (like `doActionBatch()`, where 'ActionBatch' is the name of the actual action to perform; Ex: `doHttpConnect()`
- etc.

A tip I may suggest is to read programs written by the community; they usual adopt best practices in naming conventions and you will get more familiar with "how methods are named"

Answer (score 0):

The main thing is, be consitent with your naming conventions.

I'm a .NET developer, so I found it best to follow the design guidelines used by the .NET Framework.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229042.aspx